# qemu launch with the seabios

Tags: io, virtual-machine, qemu, bios

I used a modified qemu for testing the IOMMU, and I also complied the seabios, but for now, I don't know how to use the special 'seabios' with my qemu, because I need to combine them together, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your bios file to qemu with a simple command line argument: `-bios mybios`

Is this what you wanted?